# After upgrade Magento to 2.3.1, Configurable product is not displaying

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-images, magento2.3.1

We have upgraded our Magento site to Latest Magento version Magento 2.3.1,
After upgrade, We are facing error while opening configurable product as below.

```
{
    "[data-role=swatch-options]": {
        "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
            "jsonConfig": <br /> 
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUrl() on null in /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Data.php:56
Stack trace: #0 /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php(261): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data-&gt;getGalleryImages(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#1 /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php(238): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable-&gt;getOptionImages()
#2 /generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable-&gt;getJsonConfig()
#3 /vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml(16): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable\Interceptor-&gt;getJsonConfig()
#4 /v in <b>/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Data.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br />
```

Simple product details page is working fine, but having error in configurable product.
Does anybody has solution of this issue? Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ronak , have you mange to solve the issue , i am facing a similar issue

Comment: Yes,  Please have a look in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by my own. I have overridden the

> \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data

Class in my custom module and forgot to call parent constructor in my Data helper file. So I have added below line of code in file and fixed the issue.

> parent::__construct($imageHelper, $urlBuilder);

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, i have found the same issue in my code was about to answer here . Anyways thank you